# SQL Server datetime out of range issue

Tags: sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

The following query is failing with error. Datatype of all the columns are datetime.

Please help.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TalendJobAudit] ([FeedFileGenDate], [StartTime], [EndTime], [ElapsedTime])
VALUES ('2000-00-00 10:00:00', '2000-00-00 10:00:00', '2000-00-00 10:00:00', '2000-00-00 10:00:00')
GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What date is `2000-00-00`? You meant `2000-01-01`?

Comment: What is `'2000-00-00 10:00:00'` supposed to be?  It is not a valid date time.  Do you intend: '2000-01-01 10:00:00'?

Comment: Oh No.careless mistake.I gave correct date and it worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a PEBCAK

Comment: I am agree with @SalmanA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 0 month or 0 day.  Your code works fine with correct values:

```
INSERT INTO TalendJobAudit (FeedFileGenDate, StartTime, EndTime, ElapsedTime)
    VALUES('2000-01-01 10:00:00',
           '2000-01-01 10:00:00',
           '2000-01-01 10:00:00',
           '2000-01-01 10:00:00'
          );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7e8f) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

2000-00-00 is not a valid date, please use correct date in place.